# Using keyCode 8 and 46 doesn't delete char on backspace on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In my application, in a text box I have the following piece of code that removes the characters on keys <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd>:

```
if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46)  {
    var currentIndex = getCaret($(this).get(0))
    alert(currentIndex);

}
```

`currentIndex` gives me the total no of characters entered in a textbox and if I put `alert(currentIndex);`
when I use a <kbd>backspace</kbd> Alert of `currentIndex` comes and and click of <kbd>OK</kbd> of Alert it deletes a chars in a text box.
**If I remove the alert `alert(currentIndex);`, it doesnt delete any char on backspace key.**

Please suggest a solution.

Adding `getCaret` function code:

```
function getCaret(el) {
    if (el.selectionEnd) {
        return el.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        el.focus();

        var r = document.selection.createRange();
        if (r == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        var re = el.createTextRange(), rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
        return rc.text.length;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `$(this).get(0)`? Isn't `this` enough? Anyway I think we need the `getCaret` function

Comment: @LightStyle 
I did not get you, please elaborate

Comment: I think `$(this).get(0)` is redundant, it returns `this` assuming that that code is called inside a jQuery function... You should post more code, especially the `getCaret` function, or maybe you can do a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)